# Vertical Raw Names in JSF datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

In below JSF page, I am trying to print out the following table view and get a single-line empty raw in the browser. What do you think I am doing wrong?

```
 -----------------------
 Up Time:        |  3  |   
 Cpu Load 1 Min: |  2  |
 Cpu Load 5 Min: |  4  |
 Cpu Load 15 Min:|  5  |
 Free Mem:       |  6  |
 Tot Mem:        |  9  |
 Dae Mem:        |  1  |
 -----------------------

     <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>

  <f:view><html>
    <head>
        <title>
            PmCounters Web Interface
        </title>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>

        <!-- Set GWT property to get browsers locale -->
        <meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=en_US">
        <base href="http://10.64.85.10/opennms/" />

        <!--   -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://10.64.85.10/opennms/css/styles.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://10.64.85.10/opennms/css/gwt-asset.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://10.64.85.10/opennms/css/onms-gwt-chrome.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://10.64.85.10/opennms/css/print.css" media="print" />

    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <br><br><br>

        <h:dataTable value="#{sysInfoTableDAO.sysInfoItem}" var="row" bgcolor="#F1F1F1" border="10" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" rows="4" width="50%" dir="LTR" frame="hsides" rules="all" summary="DAE PM Counters Display." >
```

Below is the place where I generate this table. St must be wrong with this.

```
              <%-- 
              HERE is the place where the table should be printed
              --%>

            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Up Time:"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{row.getUpTime()}"/>
                <h:outputText value="Cpu Load 1 Min:"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{row.getCpuLoad1min()}"/>
                <h:outputText value="Cpu Load 5 Min:"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{row.getCpuLoad5min()}"/>
                <h:outputText value="Cpu Load 15 Min:"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{row.getCpuLoad15min()}"/>
                <h:outputText value="Free Mem:"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{row.getCpufreeMem()}"/>
                <h:outputText value="Tot Mem:"/>                                       
                <h:outputText value="#{row.getTotMem()}"/>
                <h:outputText value="Dae Mem:"/>                                       
                <h:outputText value="#{row.getDaeMem()}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:dataTable>






    </center>
</body></html></f:view>
```

Answer (score 0):

In other words, JSF tags are not parsed and appear plain in the produced HTML output? That can only mean that the `FacesServlet` has not been invoked. You need to make sure that the request URL as appears in browser address bar matches the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` as definied in `web.xml`. If it's for example `*.jsf`, then you should open the page by `page.jsf` and not by `page.jsp`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, as you tagged the question with "jsf-2.0", you seem to be using JSF 2.0. Why are you then using legacy JSP instead of its successor Facelets which is the default view technology since JSF 2.0?

Comment: I am pretty much new to this and getting some examples from google to learn the thing. Naming it .jsp was not on purpose. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You should concentrate on JSF 2.x resources, not on the JSF 1.x ones. Start with Oracle's own official JSF tutorial. You can also find some links in our JSF wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: I renamed it to.jsf and referred to it in we.xml. However, now the browser merely shows the source code of jsf page. Any sugestion?